# Refreshing counter in jLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Is there any way to refresh the counter in jLabel when a button
 is on click? I tried with repaint(), revalidate() methods already but all does not work.

When like button is on click :

```
    jButton_like.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                int count = 1;
                eForumLikeCounter likeAmount = new eForumLikeCounter(
                        userName, topicId, count);
                if (likeAmount.checkLikeAmount() == true) {
                    JOptionPane
                            .showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Unable to perform like on the same thread by the same user");
                } else if (likeAmount.checkDislikeExists() == true) {
                    JOptionPane
                            .showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "You can only either like or dislike this thread");
                } else {
                    likeAmount.likeCounter();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Set up for database :

```
    public void SetUpLikeDislikeAmount() {
    int likes = 0;
    int dislike = 0;
    // Set Up Database Source
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "Select likeDislike_likes,likeDislike_dislike from forumLikeDislike WHERE likeDislike_topics = "
            + topicId + "";
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    // Call readRequest to get the result
    resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            likes += resultSet.getInt("likeDislike_likes");
            dislike += resultSet.getInt("likeDislike_dislike");
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    jLabel_like.setText(Integer.toString(likes));
    jLabel_dislike.setText(Integer.toString(dislike));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For sooner help post SSCCE ?

Comment: I try to do like the like and dislike system. So whenever the button is on click, the value in label will be refreshed. The data in database work perfectly, just that I do not know how to refresh/update jLabel.

Comment: Use `JLabel.setText` method when ever a click happens.

Comment: Ya I tried already. But it said cannot convert from void method to string

Comment: Oh ya. It fixed already. I just simply call the setUpLikeDislikeAmount method when the button is on click. I need not to set the test in jLabel again because it is in that method already. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `setText()` method of the `JLabel`. Probably something like:

```
counter.setText("");
```

or

```
counter.setText("0");
```

Comment: I tried label.setText(SetUpLikeDislikeAmount()); but there is an error about what cannot convert from void to string.

Comment: The setText() method needs a String as a parameter. You should read the javadocs for JLabel.